# How to position the arrow of this widget correctly?

Tags: html, css, css-float

The html code for the widget header is as follows.

```
    <div class="widget-header">
                        <span>caption</span>
                                                    <a href="sh/index.php?type=rec">more</a>
                        <img src="/img/widgets/widgets_more.gif" />

    </div>
```

My CSS code is

```
.widget-header span { float: left; }
.widget-header a, img { float: right; }
```

If this, the widgets_more right arrow would position to the left of text 'more' like this,
[image]

How can I get the right order with modifying the css code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of placing the arrow next to the link as an image, you should set it as a background image in a class.

Something like this should do it (untested but should work):

**CSS:**

```
a.widgets-more{
    background-image:url(/img/widgets/widgets_more.gif);
    background-position:right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

If you want the link to appear on the left of the link, then use the following:

```
a.widgets-more{
    background-image:url(/img/widgets/widgets_more.gif);
    background-position:left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

Then apply the **class to your link**:

```
<a class="widgets-more" href="sh/index.php?type=rec">more</a>
```

Also, the element **floated to the right** *should be stacked above the element floated to the left*. So rearrange your HTML to look like this:

```
<div class="widget-header">
    <a class="widgets-more" href="sh/index.php?type=rec">more</a>
    <span>caption</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Complete and elegant answer, helps a lot, but could you give any reference to 'the element floated to the right should be stacked above the element floated to the left. '

Comment: @Jichao: Glad you found the answer helpful. I was unable to find an article specifically explaining why an element that is floated to the right needs to be placed above/before other elements (including elements floated left) however, I did stumble across an interesting article on Smashing Magazine about floats if you are interested: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/